# How do I get an average from this output and convert currency to EUR like the rest if any of the numbers is a british pound?

Tags: python, average, screen-scraping, currency, price

I tried many ways but always get errors.. I just want to convert the sterling ones to euro, make exclusions if result is any of the following : 123, 1234, 12345 , and in the end have 1 output; the average of all the numbers.

```
import requests
import re
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.donedeal.ie/cars/Ford/C-MAX"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for price in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'card__price'}):
    price = price.text
```

The output of that so far looks like:

```
€1,350
€17,950
€650
... (and so on)
```

now for the currency conversion..

```
    pound_price= re.compile(r'£+\d[0-9,.]+')
    if pound_price.findall(price):
        converted=price[0]#.replace('£','')
        converted=c.convert(price[0], 'GBP', 'EUR')
        print(converted)
```

It returns no output and this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx", line 32, in <module>
    converted=c.convert(price[0], 'GBP', 'EUR')
  File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\currency_converter\currency_converter.py", line 358, in convert
    return self.cast(amount) / r0 * r1
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '£'
```

```
    price_only = re.compile(r'\d[0-9,.]+')
    just_price = price_only.findall(price)

    integer_price = [int(''.join(s[0:].split(','))) for s in just_price]

    def cal_average(num):
        sum_num=0
        for t in (num):
            sum_num= sum_num + t
        avg= sum_num / len(num)
        return avg

    print(int(cal_average(integer_price)))
```

Output looks like:

```
1350
17950
650
19950
24368
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx", line 60, in <module>
    print(int(cal_average(integer_price)))
  File "xx", line 57, in cal_average
    avg= sum_num / len(num)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
15950
7250
7500
5250
113
14500
314
13450
999

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: It appears that your 6th input set from `soup.findAll` is an empty list.  Since you neglected to trace your execution or give us the minimal code to do that ourselves, we can't get more specific.

Comment: @Prune edited it now